# Need a basic working of git

Tags: git

Recently i am asked to move my projects to git.Can please someone tell me how to achieve the following.

i have my project in our local server, I create a local repository using `git init`.

Then i create a new project in git server and add the remote URL to my local repository.
After that i do `git push`.

Now my project development is done by 3 developers simultaneously.

> Now how to do i achieve this?

Suppose if i am creating a TAG after every new release.

> Now if i want to give  a hot fix for 4 version before my main release how do i do this?

Comment: your question is too broad.  See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve.

Answer (score 1):

Git is the ultimate tool for samll groups or for large groups.

There are several ways to work with git but before that you need to know your way around and to understand what is GIT.

Im recommending you to first all to watch this [GIT into](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDR433b0HJY) - [Introduction to Git with **Scott Chacon** of GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDR433b0HJY)

Once you feel you know your way around start to think about the desired workflow

---

#### [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Git flow is one of the most popular git workflow out there. It has a very solid structure + scripting that does all the logic for you, it supports what you asked to have **development** branch along with **hotfix**.

It handle the creation, merging, deletion and more with build in scripts.

---

> Now my project development is done by 3 developers simultaneously.
> How to do i achieve this?

- Every member of your project should clone the repository via git clone
- Give then permission(s) to write (push) to the repository
- From this point each one is working on his own copy and updating the remote repository.

---

> Suppose if i am creating a TAG after every new release.
> Now if i want to give a hot fix for 4 version before my main release how do i do this?

**[Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)** does it all for you. It create branched, merge, tag and more.
Simply start using it.